# Why is my Python multiprocess crashing when I try to run infinite loop along with gui

Tags: python, user-interface, multiprocessing, infinite-loop, irc

I haven’t coded since college and I’m new to Python so I’m coming at this as a relative novice.  My ultimate goal will be to have a gui program that will react based on commands people enter into twitch chat. I have a barebones gui created with tkinter and a bot that will monitor twitch chat.  When I run these two components separately in their own .py files they work fine.  When they are together in same program it locks up because I have two infinite loops running.  I tried threading them but this also didn’t work.  I tried using using multiprocess instead of threading, the code for which I’ve included below. I've looked at the other multiprocess and threading questions but I can't seem to figure this out.

```
from tkinter import *

# settings contains values for HOST, PORT, NICK, PASS, CHANNEL
from settings import * 

import socket
import multiprocessing

class Gui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        master.title("AftA_Bot beta")
        self.doodle = Canvas(master, width=720, height=576, bg="white")
        self.doodle.pack()
        self.out = Button(master, text="Quit", command=master.quit)
        self.out.pack()

class createbot:
    def __init__(self, server, port, username, token, channel):
        self.s = socket.socket()
        self.s.connect((server, port))
        self.channel = channel
        self.s.send(bytes("PASS " + token + "\r\n", "UTF-8"))
        self.s.send(bytes("NICK " + username + "\r\n", "UTF-8"))
        self.s.send(bytes("JOIN #" + channel + " \r\n", "UTF-8"))

        print("Connected to host")

        #  Clear initial connection text
        while True:
            line = str(self.s.recv(1024))
            if "End of /NAMES list" in line:
                break
        print("Initial login text cleared.")

    def read_chat(self):
        #  Infinite Loop to monitor chat
        while True:
            for line in str(self.s.recv(1024)).split('\\r\\n'):
                parts = line.split(':')
                if len(parts) < 3:
                    continue

                message = parts[2][:len(parts[2])]
                usernamesplit = parts[1].split("!")
                username = usernamesplit[0]
                print(username + ": " + message)


    def send_message(self, msg):
        self.s.send(bytes("PRIVMSG #" + self.channel + " :" + msg + "\r\n", "UTF-8"))



bot = createbot(HOST, PORT, NICK, PASS, CHANNEL)
botthread = multiprocessing.Process(target=bot.read_chat)

root = Tk()
mainapp = Gui(root)
guithread = multiprocessing.Process(target=root.mainloop)

try:
    botthread.start()
except:
    print("Could not start bot thread")

try:
    guithread.start()
except:
    print("Could not start gui thread")
```

The code above results in the following output/errors:

```
Connected to host
Initial login text cleared.
Connected to host
Could not start gui thread
Initial login text cleared.
Could not start bot thread
Could not start gui thread
Connected to host
Initial login text cleared.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Thom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
exitcode = _main(fd)
File "C:\Users\Thom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
Could not start bot thread
Could not start gui thread
```

Comment: No idea if this is the issue, but you pretty much always need to put any subprocess creation in a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

Comment: This actually did help (thank you), though didn't completely solve the problem.  It still won't run. I tried using threading too and still didn't work.

Comment: has the error changed?

Comment: I've worked it out actually.  Apparently if you use tkinter and want to create thread it must come from inside the root.mainloop().  It's still buggy as hell but it's progressing.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I didn't think of that, but I have heard of things like that before. Qt actually implements its own thread class to allow for a similar thing